# When right clicking or displaying menu on Windows 8, menu is shown on bottom-left side

Tags: windows-8

I have recently bought Windows 8 PC. There is a strange issue that I am facing.

Whenever I right click the context menu is displayed on the bottom-left side.

[image: Context menu being displayed on the bottom-left side]

Even the menu in programs like IrfanView get displayed on bottom-left side.

[image: IrfanView menu displayed on bottom-left side]

But in case of Google Chrome and Mozilla Firefox it is displayed on the bottom-right side as usual.

[image: Context menu on bottom-right side in case of Google Chrome]

I can't find any setting for this one. How can this behavior be changed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just have the wrong handedness in your Windows configuration.

Execute `explorer shell:::{80F3F1D5-FECA-45F3-BC32-752C152E456E}` from the run dialog (Win + R), go to "Other" tab and change the handedness.

Answer (score 2):

I have already accepted the answer but if you want to go via the GUI route then search for "tablet" in Charms and in "Settings" go to "Tablet PC Settings".

[image]

In the "Other" tab select "Left Handed" for "Handedness".

[image]